# R Shiny key input binding

Tags: r, shiny

In a Shiny application, is it possible to have a binding that listens to what key a user presses down?

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript, but I'm looking for something like:

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    alert(code);
};
```

where the key input is then to be used in `server.R`, e.g.:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$text <- renderText({
    paste('You have pressed the following key:', input$key)
  })

  # ...

})
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add a listener for keypresses. The `Shiny.onInputChange` can be used to bind the key pressed to a shiny variable:

```
library(shiny)
runApp( list(ui = bootstrapPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("results"),
  tags$script('
    $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", e.which);
    });
  ') 
)
, server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$results = renderPrint({
    input$mydata
  })
}
))
```

for `keydown` events you can substitute:

```
  tags$script('
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", e.which);
    });
  ')
```

Comment: Happy to help. You will need to look around for a table of keyboard keycodes.

Comment: This was very helpful. It seems though that it doesn't work with arrows, shift keys etc... and typing a letter with caps on or off yields a recent result. It seems it really observes what "character" is typed. Any way to make it work with arrows ?

Comment: for non character keys to work you need keydown/keyup instead of key press: [see here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events#working-with-scan-codes-keydown-keyup)

Comment: why would keydown occur only once if key is pressed multiple times?

Comment: @Valentas Reactive variables in Shiny will only trigger when a variable changes. If the same key is pressed multiple times in a row, the variable is being set but not changed, so functions using that value won't trigger.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this great solution. Just a remark, when you need to use a `shinydashboard` page, the `tag$script` part need to be placed inside the `dashboardBody` part.

Comment: I found linked solution useful if e.g. the enter key should activate a search input typed into a textbox. If courser is not in text field, ienter will not trigger search yet https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/proxy-click/app.R

Comment: Two remarks here: use `Shiny.setInputValue` since `Shiny.onInputChange` is [deprecated](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html). Use `{
    key: e.which,
    nonce: Math.random()
  }` to send on every key press.

Answer (score 5):

I've been working on an R package `{keys}` to solve this problem. It's basically a wrapper around the [Mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) javascript library. With this, observing keys is an easy task:

```r
library(shiny)
library(keys)

hotkeys <- c(
  "1", 
  "command+shift+k", 
  "up up down down left right left right b a enter"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useKeys(),
  keysInput("keys", hotkeys)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$keys, {
    print(input$keys)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

More information here: https://github.com/r4fun/keys

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer to highlight what @Davor Josipovic says in comments:

1. `Shiny.onInputChange` is deprecated in favor of `Shiny.setInputValue`.
2. `Shiny.setInputValue` allows to more elegant solution for a problem with the same key event pressed twice (or more) in a row (by default in this situation event won't be trigger, because `input$` do not change) - it is not necessary to use `counter` variable or `Math.random()` method, just `{priority: "event"}`:

```
library(shiny)

tags$script(HTML('
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  Shiny.setInputValue("key_pressed", e.key, {priority: "event"});
    });
'))
```

[Communicating with Shiny via JavaScript](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)

Above I have used classic approach with JavaScript instead of jQuery and also I have used `e.key` instead of `e.which` or `e.keyCode` (both deprecated) [Difference](https://thisthat.dev/key-vs-key-code-vs-which/)

Answer (score 2):

Building on @jdharrison and @gringer, I wanted a listener that would track not just whether a key has been pressed, but which keys are presently pressed/down.

This gives me the following:

```r
library(shiny)

ui = bootstrapPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("results"),
  ## keydown
  tags$script('
    downKeyCount = 0;
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("downKey", downKeyCount++);
       Shiny.onInputChange("downKeyId", e.code);
    });'
  ),
  ## keyup
  tags$script('
    upKeyCount = 0;
    $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("upKey", upKeyCount++);
       Shiny.onInputChange("upKeyId", e.code);
    });'
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  keyRecords = reactiveValues()

  output$results = renderPrint({ 
    keys = reactiveValuesToList(keyRecords);
    names(keys[unlist(keys)]);
  })
  observeEvent(input$downKey, { keyRecords[[input$downKeyId]] = TRUE });
  observeEvent(input$upKey, { keyRecords[[input$upKeyId]] = FALSE });
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Key details/changes from above:

- We use `e.code` instead of `e.which` as this gives us a more useful description of what keys are pressed. E.g. `"KeyA"` instead of `65`. However, this means we can not distinguish between capitals and lower case.
- We use `keydown` and `keyup` instead of `keypress` as `keypress` appears to timeout. So if you press-and-hold a key, `keypress` will be active (return TRUE) for 1-2 seconds and then be inactive (return FALSE).
- We initially used the simple listener by @jdharrison. However we use the key-pressed-count method by @gringer in our code above as otherwise pressing or releasing the same key twice in a row does not respond. But if you want to force users to alternate key presses, then we recommend the simple listener.

Shiny v1.4, R v3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work for multiple presses, you can create an additional press counter that updates on a key press (following the increment convention used in Shiny), bind that value to a different variable, and watch the counter rather than the key code. Here's some example UI code:

```
  tags$script('
    pressedKeyCount = 0;
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("pressedKey", pressedKeyCount++);
       Shiny.onInputChange("pressedKeyId", e.which);
    });'
  )
```

And associated server code:

```
  observeEvent(input$pressedKey, {
    if(input$pressedKeyId >= 49 && input$pressedKeyId <= 57){ # numbers
      values$numClick <- (input$pressedKeyId - 48);
      flipNumber();
    }
    if(input$pressedKeyId >= 37 && input$pressedKeyId <= 40){ # arrow keys
      arrowCode <- input$pressedKeyId - 37;
      xInc <- ((arrowCode+1) %% 2) * (arrowCode - 1);
      yInc <- ((arrowCode) %% 2) * (arrowCode - 2) * -1;
      if(!any(values$click == c(-1,-1))){
        values$click <- (((values$click - 1) + c(xInc, yInc) + 9) %% 9) + 1;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: No need to complicate: you can simply send `{
    key: e.which,
    nonce: Math.random()
  }`. Since nonce is random and different on each key-press, the message will be sent every time.

Comment: I don't agree that a random number generator is simpler (or less computationally intensive) than an incrementing value. It's also not guaranteed to be non-repeating (although the likelihood of that is very small with a floating point value).