# Shiny Responds to Enter

Tags: r, shiny

I have a textInput widget, and now whenever I start typing in the widget, shinyApp tries to evaluate the unfinished content in the textInput widget and results in many errors. I'm aware that adding an action Button "Calculate" would easily solve the problem. However, my app does not have space left for one more button. So, I'd like to know if there's a way that the textInput widget would "listen" to a keyboard event, such as when the user hits "Enter?" Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973549/r-shiny-key-input-binding

Comment: Glad I could be helpful!

Comment: @MillerZhu her name is Jimbo

Comment: @AndyYao By the time I commented he was still Eugene...Is the earth still self-spinning in 24 hrs?

Comment: @MillerZhu look at the sky. How many moons are there???

Comment: @AndyYao There's only a tiger's tail pointing to the left...

Comment: @MillerZhu Is your question solved?

Comment: @Braisly Not yet. Do you have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @MillerZhu Not but I have different possibilities, I will try some of them and I answer this question for you and the community.

Comment: @Braisly Thank you! I look forward to it!

Comment: @MillerZhu Do you see my answer? Tell if you get it or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case, the problem is reactive programming and this is the reason that you need something to manage this situation. My recommendation is to use [observer pattern](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) or  [validate function](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/validate.html).

- **Observer pattern**: shiny implements the observer pattern which is
  useful to act when an event happens in an object (it can be a click
  in a button, new value in an input...).
- **Validate function**: the functionality of this process is similar to an
  if/else statement. Indeed, there is *need* what is the if to check the 
  parameter, if the values are wrong, there will be an error message.

To know how to use observe pattern and the validate function, click on the previous link (in the Shiny website is everything explained).

Answer (score 17):

Very good question. Here is an example of the way I use; this app shows a ggplot and the user gives the title of the ggplot in a textbox - but the title changes reacts only when "Return" is pressed:

```
js <- '
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    Shiny.onInputChange("keyPressed", Math.random());
  }
});
'

shinyApp(
  ui = bootstrapPage(

    tags$script(js),

    textInput("title", label = "Title"),

    plotOutput("ggplot")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    Title <- reactiveVal()

    observeEvent(input[["keyPressed"]], {
      Title(input[["title"]])
    })

    output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point() +
        ggtitle(Title())
    })

  }
)
```

## Explanations:

This Javascript code:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    Shiny.onInputChange("keyPressed", Math.random());
  }
});
```

creates a new Shiny input, namely `input$keyPressed` which receives a random number when the "Return" key is pressed anywhere.

Then I define a reactive value which takes the value `input$title` given in the textbox by the user, only when `input$keyPressed` changes:

```
Title <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input[["keyPressed"]], {
  Title(input[["title"]])
})
```

And finally I pass this reactive value to `ggtitle`:

```
output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(Title())
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an app that I built, and solves a similar problem.

The idea is to have listen to both the keypress and the button, and make sure they work together well. In your case, you should be able to make something even simpler because you don't need the button.

I hope you like it.

```
library(shiny)
# This is a demo app to test a key binding on an actionButton
# Uncommenting the info item (on both UI and server) will display internal stuff
runApp( 
  list(
    #############################################
    # UI 
    #############################################
    ui = bootstrapPage(
      textInput ("myinput", label = "Write something here"),
      tags$script('
        $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        Shiny.onInputChange("lastkeypresscode", e.keyCode);
        });
        '),
      actionButton("GO", "Lancer le matching !"),
      # verbatimTextOutput("info"),
      verbatimTextOutput("results")
    ), 

    #############################################
    # SERVER 
    #############################################
    server = function(input, output, session) {

      # There are state variables for the input text and GO button
      curr.val <- "" # Corresponds to the current displayed input$myinput
      curr.go  <- 0  # Corresponds to the last known GO value (integer)

      lastEvent <- reactive({
        # Is reactive to the following events
        input$GO
        input$lastkeypresscode

        # Decide which action should be taken
        if(input$GO > curr.go) {
          # The user pushed the GO actionButton, so take action
          action <- 1
          curr.go <<- input$GO
        } else if(input$lastkeypresscode == 13) {
          # The user pressed the Enter key, so take action
          action <- 1
        } else {
          # The user did anything else, so do nothing
          action <- 0
        }

        return(action)
      })

      output$results = renderPrint({
        if(lastEvent() == 1) {
          curr.val <<- isolate(input$myinput)
        }
        curr.val
      })

      # output$info = renderText({
      #   paste(curr.val, curr.go, input$lastkeypresscode, sep = ", ")
      # })
    }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple app as an example, where the user can write the name of a city and after pressing ENTER it returns latitude and longitude:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)


runApp( 
  list(
    #############################################
    # UI 
    #############################################
ui = fluidPage( title = "City Search" ,
                position= "static-top",
                tags$script(' $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
                                                  Shiny.onInputChange("lastkeypresscode", e.keyCode);
                                                  });
                                                  '),
                # Search panel:
                textInput("search_city", "" , placeholder= "City"),
                verbatimTextOutput("results")), 

    #############################################
    # SERVER 
    #############################################
server = function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$lastkeypresscode)) {
      if(input$lastkeypresscode == 13){
        target_pos = geocode(input$search_city, messaging =FALSE)
        LAT = target_pos$lat
        LONG = target_pos$lon
        if (is.null(input$search_city) || input$search_city == "")
          return()
        output$results = renderPrint({
          sprintf("Longitude: %s ---- Latitude: %s", LONG, LAT)
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
)
)
```

Note that for catching the ENTER input the code is 13, i.e. `input$lastkeypresscode == 13`.