# Enabling and then disabling reactive events based on user input

Tags: shiny

I am trying to create an app that allows the user to search on a custom term, The logic i am trying to create is the user, inputs a string, and presses ENTER on the key board, the the search term is executed, this has been achievable. However in the example below after you press the enter button, it executes all changes, in the textinput

I have tried resetting the last key to empty, etc but have had no luck figuring out this little problem, simplified code below

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("example"),

   fluidRow( 
     column( 3, offset = 1,
             tags$script(' $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
                                                  Shiny.onInputChange("lastkeypresscode", e.keyCode);
                                                  });
                                                  '),
     textInput("searchtext", 
               label = "Text input",
               value = "")),
     column( 4, textOutput("mysearch")),
     column( 4) 
    )



server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$lastkeypresscode)){
      if(input$lastkeypresscode == 13){
         output$mysearch <- renderText(input$searchtext)

      }
    }
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The expected output is that changes should only be seen in the text out put after the ENTER key is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an `onKeyPress` event handler to the text input:

```
library(shiny)

textInput2 <- function(inputId, label, value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL){
  input <- textInput(inputId, label, value, width, placeholder)
  input$children[[2]] <- 
    htmltools::tagAppendAttributes(
      input$children[[2]], 
      onKeyPress = sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s_keypress', event.key)", inputId))
  input
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput2("textinput", "Enter text:"),
  textOutput("textoutput")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input[["textinput_keypress"]], {
    if(input[["textinput_keypress"]] == "Enter"){
      output[["textoutput"]] <- renderText({
        input[["textinput"]]
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Some people say that it is not recommended to define an `output` inside an observer. To avoid that, you can do:

```
server <- function(input, output){

  Text <- eventReactive(input[["textinput_keypress"]], {
    req(input[["textinput_keypress"]] == "Enter")
    input[["textinput"]]
  })

  output[["textoutput"]] <- renderText({
    Text()
  })

}
```

Alternatively, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415301/shiny-responds-to-enter/46475587#46475587). But the present answer is better, I think.

---

## EDIT

The OP claims that does not work. Maybe a more robust solution is:

```
onKeyPress = sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s_keypress', event.which)", inputId)
```

and replace

```
input[["textinput_keypress"]] == "Enter"
```

with

```
input[["textinput_keypress"]] == 13
```

Comment: Hi @ Stéphane Laurent, I ran the code you have provided, and I see the screen with the Enter text: box, I have entered a search term, then pressed the enter key, nothing happened.

Comment: Hello @Pythonuser. Please see my edit, does it work ? Are you opening the app in the RStudio browser ? There are issues with this browser. It's better to use a true browser like Chrome.