# Shiny responds to enter, a not-quite-working example

Tags: r, shiny

Looking at the earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415301/shiny-responds-to-enter) I've tried to implement a simple example where the number entered changes the data used in ggplot.

Two things aren't working:

1) The first time the app is run the graph is not drawn (or redrawn) until enter is pressed. Then, if you hit backspace making the year equal to 195, the graph redraws apparently ignoring the code, `if(input$lastkeypresscode == 13)`.

2) The graph is not drawn initially. Likely because enter is not pressed.

How do I fix these two issues such that the graph is initially drawn with year = 1950 and then only redrawn when enter is pressed?

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(numericInput("start_year", "Enter", 1950)),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$script('
    $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
       Shiny.onInputChange("lastkeypresscode", e.which);
    });
    '), 
    box(plotOutput("temp_plot")) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  observe({  

    if(!is.null(input$lastkeypresscode)){
      if(input$lastkeypresscode == 13){

        output$temp_plot <- renderPlot({

          years = 1912:1971
          df <- tibble(nhtemp) %>% 
            mutate(year = years) %>% 
            filter(year > input$start_year)

          ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = nhtemp)) +
            geom_line()
        })
      }  
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you need:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

years = 1912:1971

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(numericInput("start_year", "Enter", 1950)),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$script('
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13){
                Shiny.onInputChange("keyPressed", Math.random());
                }
                });
                '), 
    box(plotOutput("temp_plot")) 
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

    the_year <- reactiveVal()

    observeEvent(input[["keyPressed"]], {
      the_year(input[["start_year"]])
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    output$temp_plot <- renderPlot({
          df <- tibble(nhtemp) %>% 
            mutate(year = years) %>% 
            filter(year > the_year())

          ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = nhtemp)) +
            geom_line()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I notice you use this convention `input[["keyPressed"]]` rather than this, `input$keyPressed`. Is it better/faster/clearer? Or just personal preference?

Comment: It was just from an example I copied and modified. I don't have a preference.