# Reactive input in RShiny reacts too quickly (without using a button)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

How do I make it so that Shiny waits a little bit for the user to input their zip code (without using a button). The problem I'm facing is that it will quickly jump to the error if the user isn't fast enough at inputting their zip code.
Edit:

- I have other user inputs in this app, but I simplified it in this question. I want all of the other inputs to be reacted to right away since they are radioButtons. I think pressing 'return' would still do the same thing as a button, which isn't what I'm looking for. I was thinking about using ' Sys.sleep()' only for the zipcode input and not for the others. Would that be possible?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui <- fluidPage(sidebarPanel(
  "",
  textInput("zipcode", label = "Enter your zipcode.", value = 98125)
  
)) ,


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$zipcode, {
    #limits zipcode input to 5 numbers only
    if (nchar(input$zipcode) != 5)
    {
      updateTextInput(session, 'zipcode', value = 98125)
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error!",
          "Only 5-character entries are permitted.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
    }
    if (is.na(as.numeric(input$zipcode)))
    {
      showModal(
        modalDialog(
          title = "Error!",
          "Only numeric values are allowed. Please try again.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        )
      )
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: One easy way would be to add a button they would click when they were done entering their zip code.  Would that work?

Comment: I didn't want to add a button-- is there a way around that?

Comment: of course there is such

Comment: I will be great if you reformat  this code, in RStudio Ctrl+Shift+A. Thanks

Comment: Is this going to be a pleasant UI experience?  Another approach is to put `req(nchar(input$zipcode) == 5)` in all of the reactives that depend on the zip code.  You can also use `validate(need(nchar(input$zipcode) == 5, message = "Only 5-character zip entries are permitted."))` to give an error at the place of the output that needed the zip.

Comment: @MichaelDewar, I agree that your solution also works well, but I'm wondering how it would work for zip codes that have leading zeros like 00501. The nchar for this zip would be 3 characters. What would be the best way to account for this?

Comment: @youtube The `input$zipcode` will be a character string, so leading zeros will still have `nchar(input$zipcode) == 5`.  You probably need to use the condition `nchar(input$zipcode) == 5 & !is.na(as.numeric(input$zipcode))` inside the `req` or `validate(need())`.  If `input$zipcode` is used in many places, you could use `clean_zip <- reactive(validate(need(nchar(input$zipcode) == 5 & !is.na(as.numeric(input$zipcode))), message = "Only 5-digit zip allowed."); input$zipcode)` and then anywhere you use it, you just need to put a `req(clean_zip())` at the top.

Comment: Whatever method you use, I suggest that you simplify things and use `&` to join both conditions into one test.  A single error message about 5-digit zips is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`debounce`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/debounce.html):

> This lets you ignore a very "chatty" reactive expression until it becomes idle, which is useful when the intermediate values don't matter as much as the final value

You don't need `Sys.sleep`, it will wait `millis` milliseconds before triggering the reactives :

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage( 
    sidebarPanel("", textInput("zipcode", label="Enter your zipcode.", value = 98125)
                 
    )  ) , 
  
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    zipcode <- reactive(input$zipcode)
    zipcode_d <- debounce(zipcode, millis = 2000)
    observeEvent(zipcode_d(),{     #limits zipcode input to 5 numbers only
      if(nchar(zipcode_d())!=5)
      {
        updateTextInput(session,'zipcode',value=98125)
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "Error!",
          "Only 5-character entries are permitted.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        ))
      }
      if(is.na(as.numeric(zipcode_d())))
      {
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "Error!",
          "Only numeric values are allowed. Please try again.",
          easyClose = TRUE
        ))
      }
    }
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

JS code added, input$keyPressed which receives a random number when the "Return" key is pressed anywhere.

```r
library(shiny)

js <- '
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    Shiny.onInputChange("keyPressed", Math.random());
  }
});
'

shinyApp(ui <- fluidPage(tags$script(js),
                         sidebarPanel(
                           "",
                           textInput("zipcode", label = "Enter your zipcode.", value = 98125),
                           textOutput("zip")
                         )) ,
         
         server <- function(input, output, session) {
           observeEvent(input[["keyPressed"]], {
             #limits zipcode input to 5 numbers only
             if (nchar(input$zipcode) != 5)
             {
               updateTextInput(session, 'zipcode', value = 98125)
               showModal(
                 modalDialog(
                   title = "Error!",
                   "Only 5-character entries are permitted.",
                   easyClose = TRUE
                 )
               )
             }
             if (is.na(as.numeric(input$zipcode)))
             {
               showModal(
                 modalDialog(
                   title = "Error!",
                   "Only numeric values are allowed. Please try again.",
                   easyClose = TRUE
                 )
               )
             }
             output$zip <- renderText(input$zipcode)
           })
         })
```

linked to: [Shiny Responds to Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415301/shiny-responds-to-enter)

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I have other user inputs in this app, but I simplified it in this question. I want all of the other inputs to be reacted to right away since they are radioButtons. I think pressing 'return' would still do the same thing as a button, which isn't what I'm looking for. I was thinking about using ' Sys.sleep()' only for the zipcode input and not for the others. Would that be possible?

Comment: So @Waldi solution might be better then. However be careful with putting such pressure on users. Giving them information how much time they still have to provide the input might be a nice idea.