# Return current position in table with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building/adding things to a Shiny application that is primarily used for users to look through a collection of plots of single samples to manually correct a single parameter for the given sample. Currently I am using a slider to flip through the plots, and a cell for the current sample will appear under the plot for the user to correct the given parameter.

This however, will require the user to move the cursor away from the slider, to the cell, and then back to the slider again. To streamline the process I thought, why not just make a reactive table that would flip through the plots when the user pressed the down key (going one cell down). This would require some sort of measuring of the current position in the table where the user is "standing". So my question is whether this can be done in the Shiny framework?

Here is a picture of how I think it could play out.

[Going one row down in the table should have a response to switch to the next plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hbzg.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, I can't really help you, but if I understand your question, you simply want a mechanism for keeping count in the server, so that you can tell what position number the user is at. Here is a simple app that keeps count of up and down button presses:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("up","Increase value"),
    tags$br(),
    actionButton("down","Decrease value")
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  ))
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
 # initiate count at zero
  count <- reactiveValues(number=0)

  observeEvent(input$up,{
    count$number <- count$number + 1
  })

  observeEvent(input$down,{
    count$number <- count$number - 1
  })

  output$value <- renderPrint({
    count$number
  })

})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Carl. This was not exactly how I imagined solving the issue. I was thinking about the possibilities of making a reactive element responding on the current writing position in an input table. I have updated my question with a simple illustration of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected column on the serverside with `DT`.

For that, you just need to replace `renderDataTable` with `DT::renderDataTable` and `dataTableOutput` with `renderDataTableOutput.`

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({ mtcars })

  output$text = renderPrint({
    cat("selected rows:", input$mytable_rows_selected)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Combining this with `DT::selectColumns` and [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973549/r-shiny-key-input-binding) should do the job.