# R Shiny key and actionButton binding to reactive values

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to make a Shiny App work where the user can manipulate `reactiveValues` with either buttons or keys. Thus a minimal example would be to increment or decrement a counter with either the Up/Down `actionButton` or the U/D keys. The user should be able to use the keys without clicking anywhere on the screen first.

Based on the examples here on SO ([Using enter key with action button in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335951/using-enter-key-with-action-button-in-r-shiny), [Shiny Responds to Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415301/shiny-responds-to-enter) and [R Shiny key input binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973549/r-shiny-key-input-binding)), I came up with the script below. However, it doesn't react at all to the U/D keys. Buttons work as expected. Once I click on a button, it gets sort of "stuck" and I can use either the Enter or Space keys to repeat the button clicks, but the U/D key has still no effect. Any idea what could be wrong?

And this is the code I wrote:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Test keyboard control"),
sidebarPanel(
    tags$script(
        'tags$head(
        $(document).keydown(function(e)){
            if (e.keyCode == 85) {
                $("#upButton").click();
            } else if (e.keyCode == 68) {
                $("#downButton").click();
            }
        });'
    ),
    actionButton("downButton", "Down"),
    actionButton("upButton", "Up")
    ),
mainPanel(htmlOutput("text"))
),

server <- function(session, input, output) {
    vals <- reactiveValues(count = 0)

    observeEvent(input$downButton, {vals$count <- vals$count - 1})
    observeEvent(input$upButton, {vals$count <- vals$count + 1})

    output$text <- renderText(paste("Counter is:", vals$count))
}
)
```

Comment: Note: This is not a duplicate! The linked questions do not adress the problem of repeated key pressing at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the input event only captures the keycode of the pressed key, which stays the same once the key is pressed. Shiny however only reacts if the event data changes. You need to set the event data to something new every time; e.g. the current time stamp. Look at this working example:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test keyboard control"),
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$script('$(document).on("keydown",
                 function (e) {
                 if(e.which == 68) {
                   Shiny.onInputChange("downButton", new Date());
                 } else if (e.which == 85) {
                   Shiny.onInputChange("upButton", new Date());
                 }
                 });
                '),
    actionButton("downButton", "Down"),
    actionButton("upButton", "Up")
  ),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput("text"))
),

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  vals <- reactiveValues(count = 0)

  observeEvent(input$downButton, {vals$count <- vals$count - 1})
  observeEvent(input$upButton, {vals$count <- vals$count + 1})

  output$text <- renderText(paste("Counter is:", vals$count))
}
)
```

Comment: Yes your example works, but I'm afraid I don't understand how to adapt it to my case. I tried to bind the key input to the actionButtons but that didn't work: 

`
 if (e.keyCode == 85) {
        Shiny.onInputChange("upButton", new Date());
    } else if (e.keyCode == 68) {
        Shiny.onInputChange("downButton", new Date());
    }
`

I also tried with separate events and `observeEvent` for the keypress, but that didn't have an effect either. I'm very new to Shiny/javascript.

Comment: Hm, I don't know what you did. I just exchanged the "script" part in your code and it worked. Anyway I have updated my answer to fit your example. If it still does not work I can only imagine your browser captures the keypress before sending it to the website. E.g. Firefox can be configured to start a website search immediately when the user enters text. In this case you will not see the keypress in Shiny.

Comment: Yes, I obviously didn't know what I was doing. In my script I had `tags$script('tags$head($(document).keydown(function(e)){...});')` which didn't work. While you are using `tags$script('$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {...})')`, which I completely overlooked...